# How do you link a shared library of a user-compiled shared library to a c++ application on Debian?

Tags: c++, debian, shared-libraries

Assume you have a shared library A.so and that another shared library, B.so, was compiled in terms of A.so. In other words,

```
ldd B.so
```

mentions A.so. Moreover, assume that A.so and B.so have been successfully compiled by myself, i.e. they are located somewhere in my home directory.

Now, I have an application App which I want to compile against A.so and B.so. Because A.so is contained in B.so, I want to link against B.so only.

So, I did that under two different linux systems. I tried on a SLES 10 SP2 and on Debian 7.7.0 (base installation, nothing special on that system). On SLES 10 SP2, this is absolutely no problem. On Debian, I get a message like the following:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccjQFzpo.o: undefined reference to symbol '_ZN2sf7secondsEf'
A.so: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

A.so can for example be a Qt4 library that I have compiled myself. If I install the Qt4 library with apt-get install, then it works.

I tried to add A.so and B.so to the list given by

```
ldconfig -v
```

i.e. I have been able to see them in this list. It doesn't solve the problem.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

> Because A.so is contained in B.so, I want to link against B.so only.

This is misunderstanding, shared library when they linked are not contained in another library or app, they are dynamically loaded. That the whole purpose of dynamic libraries vs static ones. It worked for you before because linker automatically loaded all depended libraries.

For `debian` I believe since `wheezy` they changed the DSO linking policy - depended shared library would not be linked automatically, you have to list all of them when you link your app (in your case you have to explicitly say A.so and B.so). Details can be found here https://wiki.debian.org/ToolChain/DSOLinking

Comment: How can that then be that installing Qt, for example, with synaptic, solved my problem (for that particular library)? I mean, if A.so is libQtCore.so, and I installed Qt with synaptic, then I only need to link against B.so. I don't get the DSO error message.